# validation of the class fields

Tags: jquery, validation

How to retrieve the elements associated with a class one by one.
In the form I have few fields and some numeric fields are associated with a class.Now on submit i need to validate the fields of the same class. I am using jquery for that.

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $(".numeric").each(function(intIndex)){})
});
```

this is what I am thinking about. Is my approach correct. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach looks correct; given any selector, you can apply a function to each of the matched elements with [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). Have you actually tried it yet? If so, what about it doesn't meet your needs?

If you want to prevent the form submission, you'll have to use a sentinal variable:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
   var fieldsAreValid = true;

   $(".numeric").each(function(intIndex)){
      if (/* this field isn't valid */) {
         fieldsAreValid = false;
      }
   });

   if (!fieldsAreValid)
     return false;
});
```

You should never be afraid to simply try something and see if it works. My favourite teacher used to say "Computer science is an experimental science - now get out of my office!"

Comment: @divya Please don't post code in comments; edit it into your question, if it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems technically correct but, just an FYI, there is already a framework that was build to handle this.  Why reinvent the wheel?  Have a look [jQuery Validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Answer (score 0):

Find working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ezmilhouse/ssVa9/

```
function is_numeric(mixed_var) {
    return (typeof(mixed_var) === 'number' || typeof(mixed_var) === 'string') && mixed_var !== '' && !isNaN(mixed_var);    
}

$("form").live("submit", function(){
   var val = true;
   $(this).find( 'input[type=text]' ).each(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('numeric')) {
            if (!is_numeric($(this).val())) {
                alert('Error! Field: ' + $(this).attr('name'));
                val = false;
            }
        }
    });
    if (val === false) {
        return false;
    }
});
```